# How to open a disk file with Capacitor?

Tags: vuejs2, capacitor

I'm saving a file by running the following code with `Capacitor`:

```
        Filesystem.writeFile({
          path: fileName,
          data: content,
          directory: FilesystemDirectory.Documents,
          //encoding: FilesystemEncoding.UTF8
        });
```

Now, I would like to open it (it's a pdf). However, I don't see anything in [FileSystem documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/filesystem) about how to achieve that? I'm missing a `FileOpener` function.

The goal is that it gets opened with whichever pdf app the user has in the phone.

I'm using Vuejs.

Answer (score 0):

I hope that this is helpful to you, a package for capacitor to read pdf.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-pdf-viewer-plugin